# Can't get first window of Rx's Window with FirstAsync

Tags: system.reactive

I want to separate an observable sequence (`IObservable`) into several observable sequences (the criteria is complicated, but for the sake of demonstration we can simply use count). This, quite obviously, calls for `Window`.

```
    private static IObservable<int> GenerateSequence()
    {
        return Observable.Range(1, 5);
    }

    await GenerateSequence()
            .Window(2)
            .Select((w, i) => new {i, w})
            .Do(w => w.w.Dump($"Window {w.i}"));
```

Output is as expected:

```
Window 0-->1
Window 0-->2
Window 0-->X
Window 1-->3
Window 1-->4
Window 1-->X
Window 2-->5
Window 2-->X
```

(`X`'s mark the `OnCompleted`)

Now, for some reason I want only first of those sequences. Hence, `FirstAsync`:

```
    (await GenerateSequence()
        .Window(2)
        .FirstAsync())
        .Dump("Window");
```

But the strange thing is, I get no output at all, as if the sequence I get from `FirstAsync` was completely dead.

I'm kinda new to Rx, so I'm totally lost as to what and why exactly happens here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the *solution* was quite simple (although I still don't get what happens in my original code) - use `SelectMany` to flatten the sequence:

```
GenerateSequence()
.Window(2)
.FirstAsync()
.Concat()
.Dump("SO");
```

Produces, as expected:

```
SO-->1
SO-->2
SO-->X
```

And then, to achieve my original goal - i.e., to change the monad and return the result as `Task<int[]>`:

```
GenerateSequence()
.Window(2)
.FirstAsync()
.Concat()
.ToArray()
.ToTask();
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
Your answer works. You [may want to look](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/17_SequencesOfCoincidence.html#SequencesOfCoincidence) at replacing `Window` with `Buffer`. They're virtually identical, except Buffer was meant for similar scenarios. It returns a list though instead of array:

```
var t = GenerateSequence()
    .Buffer(2)
    .FirstAsync()
    //.Select(list => list.ToArray()) //If you're particular about Task<int[]> over Task<IList<int>>
    .ToTask();
```

As another aside, `.SelectMany(i => i)` can be replaced with `.Merge()`.

*Old answer*:

---

I generally don't mix Rx with `await`. It's apparently supported, but seems... unintuitive. This code dumps the output of the first window:

```
GenerateSequence()
    .Window(2)
    .FirstAsync()
    .Subscribe(i => i.Dump("Window"));
```

This dumps the first item from each window:

```
GenerateSequence()
    .Window(2)
    .Select(o => o.FirstAsync())
    .Subscribe(i => i.Dump("Window"));
```

It wasn't clear from your question which one you wanted.

Comment: My problem is that I have to return the contents of the first window as `Task<int[]>`. If I `Subscribe` to anything, it works. But I can't leave the monad, even if I try doing it by the prescribed way.

Comment: I knew about `Buffer`. While it works in the simplified scenario I have here for an example, in my original problem I have to use `Window`s. Also thanks for the idea with `Merge`, it simplifies the code a little bit (I resorted to `Concat`, which in this case does the same, but reads better).